# Sum up the tree nodes using Java 8 Streams

Tags: recursion, java-8, java-stream

Is it possible to sum up the nodes of a tree using Java 8 streams, if possible in a one liner ?

Here is a node class

```
public class Node
{   
private int nodeNum;    
ArrayList<Node> children = new ArrayList<>();

public Node(int num)
{
    this.nodeNum = num;
}

public int getNodeNum()
{
    return nodeNum;
}

public boolean addNode(Node node)
{
    return children.add(node);
}

public ArrayList<Node> getNodes()
{
    return this.children;
}
}
```

Normal way to solve this is using a recursion and sum up the node , like the code below.

```
int getNodeSum(Node node)
{
    int total = 0;

    if(node.children.isEmpty())
        return node.getNodeNum();
    else
    {
        for(Node tempNode:node.children)
        {
            total+= getNodeSum(tempNode);
        }
        return total+node.getNodeNum();
    }
}
```

We can use streams to sum up the immediate child nodes but I'm not getting how to move deep and do it recursively using Streams.
This code only solves the problem to a single level. Any ideas?

```
total = list.stream().filter(Node -> node.children.isEmpty()).map(Node:: getNodeNum).reduce(node.getNodeNum(), (a,b) -> a+b);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution to your problem would be to use recursion along with [`Stream.flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-).

First, you'd need to add the following helper method to your `Node` class:

```
public Stream<Node> allChildren() {
    return Stream.concat(
        Stream.of(this), 
        this.children.stream().flatMap(Node::allChildren)); // recursion here
}
```

This returns a `Stream<Node>` whose elements are this node and all its descendant nodes.

Then, you could rewrite your `getNodeSum` method as follows:

```
int getNodeSum(Node node) {
    return node.allChildren()
        .mapToInt(Node::getNodeNum)
        .sum();
}
```

This uses the above defined `Node.allChildren` method along with the [`Stream.mapToInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) and [`IntStream.sum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum--) methods to calculate the total sum.

---

Alternatively, you could have a `Function<Node, Stream<Node>> descendants` attribute in your `Node` class that performs the recursion in place:

```
private Function<Node, Stream<Node>> descendants =
    node -> Stream.concat(
        Stream.of(node),
        node.children.stream()
            .flatMap(this.descendants)); // recursion here: function invoked again
```

This is a *recursive lambda expression*, since the function you are defining is at both sides of the `=` sign. This kind of lambda expressions are allowed **only as attributes of a class**, i.e. you cannot assign a recursive lambda expression to a local variable.

With that recursive function in place, you could rewrite the `allChildren` method as follows:

```
public Stream<Node> allChildren() {
    return descendants.apply(this);
}
```

Finally, the code for your `getNodeSum` method would be identical to the previous version:

```
int getNodeSum(Node node) {
    return node.allChildren()
        .mapToInt(Node::getNodeNum)
        .sum();
}
```

Note: while this approach might result attractive for some people, it might have some drawbacks, i.e. now every instance of the `Node` class has the `descendants` attribute, despite not being needed at all. You could circumvect this i.e. by having a `Tree` class with this recursive function as an attribute, and `Node` being an inner class (with the `descendants` attribute removed).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add recusive method for Node class, which wil be join child streams

```
public Stream<Node> recursiveConcat() {
    return Stream.concat(
        Stream.of(this),
        children.stream().flatMap(Node::recursiveConcat));
}
```

Then do -

```
root.recusiveConcat().mapToInt(Node::getNodeNum).sum()
```

whole code

```
public class Node {

    private int nodeNum;
    ArrayList<Node> children = new ArrayList<>();

    public Node(int num) {
        this.nodeNum = num;
    }

    public int getNodeNum() {
        return nodeNum;
    }

    public boolean addNode(Node node) {
        return children.add(node);
    }

    public ArrayList<Node> getNodes() {
        return this.children;
    }

    public Stream<Node> recursiveConcat() {
        return Stream.concat(
                Stream.of(this),
                children.stream().flatMap(Node::recursiveConcat));
    }
}


Node root = new Node(1);
Node node1 = new Node(2);
Node node2 = new Node(3);
Node node3 = new Node(4);
node2.addNode(node3);
node1.addNode(node2);
root.addNode(node1);
System.out.println(root.recursiveConcat().mapToInt(Node::getNodeNum).sum());
```